# Adding columns to DataFrame from other DataFrame without intersection

Tags: python, pandas

I have on Dataframe with diff size and columns, I require to add the columns from one DataFrame to another, and fulfill with same data all rows.

for instance:
one of them:

```
   Out[48]: 
       A  B
    0  1  2
    1  1  2
    2  1  2
    3  1  2
```

and the other

```
Out[49]: 
   C  D
0  3  4
```

I want to have a new one as:

```
   A  B C D
0  1  2 3 4
1  1  2 3 4
2  1  2 3 4
3  1  2 3 4
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **`join`** with **`ffill`**:

```
df1.join(df2).ffill().astype(int)

   A  B  C  D
0  1  2  3  4
1  1  2  3  4
2  1  2  3  4
3  1  2  3  4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `assign` with `pd.Series`

```
df.assign(**df1.loc[0])
Out[11]: 
   A  B  C  D
0  1  2  3  4
1  1  2  3  4
2  1  2  3  4
3  1  2  3  4
```